# Is it possible to use ncurses through a telnet connection?

Tags: c, telnet, ncurses, tui

I wanna use a TUI over telnet connection between two Linux boxes like ncurses, is there a way to do this or to use TUIs through telnet in C?

Comment: Is this a programming question? The way you phrase it, it sounds like a user question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to telnet to a server machine and run an ncurses application, or do you somehow want to run a UI on one machine, and a backend on the other. If it's the former, you just need to set the TERM environment variable correctly on the server machine before running your program (i.e., `export TERM=vt100`).

If it's the latter, then ncurses itself isn't going to do any networking, but you could certainly write a client that uses ncurses, and have the client talk to a server backend in some way.